# Faster way to apply raster gis data to patches netlogo

Tags: gis, netlogo

Is there a way to improve the computational time when importing raster data to patches?

Here is my code. This usually takes around 20 minutes to complete. My world is 500x500. I found that using the **gis:intersect?** is much faster than **gis:apply-coverage**, if only true or false are to be considered. Cheers.

```
 to setup-gis
  set city gis:load-dataset "GSR_GIS.shp"
  set LGA_nodes gis:load-dataset "LGA_nodes.shp"
  set builtuparea gis:load-dataset "GSR_builtuparea.shp"
  set recreationalarea gis:load-dataset "GSR_recreationalareas.shp"
  set natural gis:load-dataset "GSR_natural.shp"
  set reserves gis:load-dataset "GSR_reserves.shp"
  set rail_network gis:load-dataset "Greater_Sydney_rail_networkt.shp"
  set roads gis:load-dataset "GSR_road_network.shp"

  gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of city 
  gis:set-drawing-color white 
  gis:draw city 1 
  gis:apply-coverage city "LGA" zone 

  set patchesinlga (patch-set patches with [ zone > 0 ])

      ask patchesinlga [
    ifelse gis:intersects? builtuparea self [set builtuparea? true][set builtuparea? false]
    ifelse gis:intersects? recreationalarea self [set recreationalarea? true][set recreationalarea? false]
    ifelse gis:intersects? natural self [set natural? true][set natural? false]
    ifelse gis:intersects? reserves self [set reserves? true][set reserves? false]
    ifelse gis:intersects? roads self [set roads? true][set roads? false]
    ifelse gis:intersects? rail_network self [set rail? true][set rail? false]
    if gis:intersects? LGA_nodes self [sprout-LGAs 1 [set color red set shape "flag" set size 2 set LGAid [zone] of patch-here]]
    ]

    ask patches with [zone > 0 and (round([zone] of self) / [zone] of self) != 1][set zone 0] ;; fixed the zone floating point issue
end
```

*Note for my edit: I've found a way to make this faster by asking only patches of interest. In my case they are patches with LGA (LGA is a zoning id), so that the patches outside of my GIS map will be excluded to run the ifelse loops, at the bottom.

But is there a way to improve this?

Some runtime results

- 50*50 took 23 seconds
- 100*100 took 79.5 seconds
- 400*400 took 30 minutes

Comment: You could try a different approach where you identify which parts are going to be the same every run and separate them from any randomly generated parts of the world. Run the GIS code in its slow form, then `export-world`. You can then have `import-world` as the start of your startup procedure (which may be quicker than the GIS tools). If you do this, however, remember that everything is included, such as the random state, all the agents etc, so you will need to reset the random number generator and create all your agents after the import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem: my code took 30+ minutes to complete and my world was only 500x700 patches. The delay was not in loading the data, but in my case, displaying the data. Looking at your code above, I believe you are experiencing a similar phenomena.

In your askpatchesinlga[] procedure, you are asking each patch to check if it intersects data. I think this is what is taking so long to execute. 2500 agents at only a second each is already about 45 minutes of processing time. To speed this up, create rasters beforehand, and load them each into netlogo. That will turn 2500 commands into 7 (ish), and should reduce your processing time accordingly.

In sum: don't ask every patch to do something if you are loading data. Do the processing first and then load in finished datasets - in your case, a built-up area raster, a rec area raster, a natural area raster, etc. Any geoprocessing toolkit should be able to make these for you.

Comment: Thank you @Chris for your answer. I know this is two-year too late to say thank you. But I did use your suggestion for the work that I did at the time. Really appreciated it. :)

Comment: @z5182 very happy to help!